# How do i fit the image in the border?

Tags: html, css

How do I fit the whole image with borders as there is some space below it. AnyHelp would be appreciated, thanks . I have attached my code below, please refer it .

[image]

```css
.Details {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.flexitems {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 100px 30px 100px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 210px;
}
.sectionimg {
  /*Flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis*/
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.flexinvert {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.sectionimg img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.sectionhead {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="Details">
        <div class="flexitems">
        <div class="sectiontext">
        <p class="sectionhead">More Than 1 Lakh Collection Of Items</p>
        <p class="sectionsubhead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ratione nostrum rem in, illo repellat eius minima aspernatur beatae ipsa officiis, fugiat enim cumque magnam. Repellendus dicta amet distinctio aspernatur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sectionimg">
            <img src="Jeans.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexitems flexinvert">
        <div class="sectiontext">
            <p class="sectionhead">More Than 1 Lakh Collection Of Items</p>
            <p class="sectionsubhead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ratione nostrum rem in, illo repellat eius minima aspernatur beatae ipsa officiis, fugiat enim cumque magnam. Repellendus dicta amet distinctio aspernatur!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sectionimg">
                <img src="mainpic.png" alt="">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexitems">
            <div class="sectiontext">
                <p class="sectionhead">More Than 1 Lakh Collection Of Items</p>
                <p class="sectionsubhead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ratione nostrum rem in, illo repellat eius minima aspernatur beatae ipsa officiis, fugiat enim cumque magnam. Repellendus dicta amet distinctio aspernatur!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sectionimg">
                    <img src="shirt.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to object fit image and fullwidth its' height.

```
.sectionimg img {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do as below (I added comments where I added to your code or changed it):

```css
.Details {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.flexitems {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 100px 30px 100px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 210px;
}
.sectionimg {
  /*Flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis*/
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*Line I added*/
  height: 100px;   /*You could change to your need*/
  border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.flexinvert {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.sectionimg img {
  /*Lines I added*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.sectionhead {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="Details">
  <div class="flexitems">
    <div class="sectiontext">
      <p class="sectionhead">More Than 1 Lakh Collection Of Items</p>
      <p class="sectionsubhead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ratione nostrum rem in, illo repellat eius minima aspernatur beatae ipsa officiis, fugiat enim cumque magnam. Repellendus dicta amet distinctio aspernatur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionimg">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1645352809168-be1d1ef6d31c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexitems flexinvert">
    <div class="sectiontext">
      <p class="sectionhead">More Than 1 Lakh Collection Of Items</p>
      <p class="sectionsubhead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ratione nostrum rem in, illo repellat eius minima aspernatur beatae ipsa officiis, fugiat enim cumque magnam. Repellendus dicta amet distinctio aspernatur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionimg">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1645352809168-be1d1ef6d31c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexitems">
    <div class="sectiontext">
      <p class="sectionhead">More Than 1 Lakh Collection Of Items</p>
      <p class="sectionsubhead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ratione nostrum rem in, illo repellat eius minima aspernatur beatae ipsa officiis, fugiat enim cumque magnam. Repellendus dicta amet distinctio aspernatur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionimg">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1645352809168-be1d1ef6d31c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=975&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you're going to take this approach, I'd also recommend `align-items: center;` on `flex-items`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is specify `height: 100%;` to `.sectionimg img` so the image takes the full width and height of the parent.

```css
.Details {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.flexitems {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 100px 30px 100px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 210px;
}

.sectionimg {
  /*Flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis*/
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.flexinvert {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.sectionimg img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sectionhead {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="Details">
  <div class="flexitems">
    <div class="sectiontext">
      <p class="sectionhead">More Than 1 Lakh Collection Of Items</p>
      <p class="sectionsubhead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ratione nostrum rem in, illo repellat eius minima aspernatur beatae ipsa officiis, fugiat enim cumque magnam. Repellendus dicta amet distinctio aspernatur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionimg">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexitems flexinvert">
    <div class="sectiontext">
      <p class="sectionhead">More Than 1 Lakh Collection Of Items</p>
      <p class="sectionsubhead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ratione nostrum rem in, illo repellat eius minima aspernatur beatae ipsa officiis, fugiat enim cumque magnam. Repellendus dicta amet distinctio aspernatur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionimg">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexitems">
    <div class="sectiontext">
      <p class="sectionhead">More Than 1 Lakh Collection Of Items</p>
      <p class="sectionsubhead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque ratione nostrum rem in, illo repellat eius minima aspernatur beatae ipsa officiis, fugiat enim cumque magnam. Repellendus dicta amet distinctio aspernatur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionimg">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```